# MySql: Summing the latest amounts banked for each category and type

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, sql-order-by

I have four MySql tables (simplified here):

Table 1: factions (just a list to reference)

```
id | name
 1 | FactionName1
 2 | FactionName2
```

Table 2: currencies (just a list to reference)

```
id | name
 1 | Currency1
 2 | Currency2
 3 | Currency3
```

Table 3: events (just a list to reference)

```
id | name   | date
 1 | Evebt1 | 2013-10-16
 2 | Event2 | 2013-10-18 (Note: date out of order)
 3 | Event3 | 2013-10-17
```

Table 4: event_banking (data entered after each event, remaining amount of each currency for each group)

```
id | faction_id | currency_id | event_id | amount
 1 |          1 |           1 |        1 |     10
 2 |          1 |           1 |        2 |     20
 3 |          1 |           1 |        3 |     30
 4 |          1 |           2 |        1 |     40
 5 |          1 |           2 |        2 |     50
 6 |          1 |           2 |        3 |     60
 7 |          1 |           3 |        1 |     70
 8 |          1 |           3 |        2 |     80
 9 |          1 |           3 |        3 |     90
10 |          2 |           1 |        1 |    100
11 |          2 |           1 |        2 |    110
12 |          2 |           1 |        3 |    120
13 |          2 |           2 |        1 |    130
14 |          2 |           2 |        2 |    140
15 |          2 |           2 |        3 |    150
16 |          2 |           3 |        1 |    160
17 |          2 |           3 |        3 |    170
```

Note: Faction 2 didn't bank Currency 3 for Event 2

What I'm looking to be able to do is to get, for each currency, the total of the last banked (date wise) for each faction. (ie How much of each currency is currently banked in total if all factions are merged)

So, I need a table looking something like:

```
currency_id | total
          1 |   130  (eg 20 + 110)
          2 |   190  (eg 50 + 140)
          3 |   250  (eg 80 + 170) <- Uses Event 3 for Group 2 as Event 2 doesn't exist
```

I can do basic joins etc, but I'm struggling to be able to filter the results so that I get the latest results for each Faction x Currency x Event so I can then sum them together to get the final total amounts for each currency.

I've tried various permutations of LEFT OUTER JOINs, GROUP BYss & HAVING COUNTs, and had some interesting (but incorrect results), and a variety of different error codes, but nothing remotely close to what I need.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can go on with something like this:

```
select eb.currency_id, sum(amount) as total 
from events e 
inner join (
   select faction_id, currency_id, max(date) as md
   from event_banking eb
   inner join events e
   on eb.event_id = e.id
   group by faction_id, currency_id
) a 
on e.date = a.md
inner join event_banking eb
on e.id = eb.event_id
and a.faction_id = eb.faction_id
and a.currency_id = eb.currency_id
group by currency_id;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f418d/16)